# JSONPath - Flow vs. Goessner

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I've got a JSON payload like this:

```
{
    "food": [
        {
            "sections": [
                {
                    "extras": [
                        {
                            "_id": "test"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "stub": "pizza"
        }
    ]
}
```

That array of food is actually quite long, and I want to filter the array by the value of 'stub'.

I was using this JSONPath expression and I swear it was working, but now it appears it isn't? I'm [testing it here](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/), and when selecting Flow's JSONPath implementation, it works, but using Goessner's, it's returning just `false`.

```
$.food[?(@.stub=='pizza')]
```

Comment: Update: it appears this may be broken in the JSONPath expression tester. I've submitted a support request for more information.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is correct.  Testing it out on http://www.jsonquerytool.com which uses Goessner's JSON Path 0.8.0 yields:

```
[
    {
        "sections": [
            {
                "extras": [
                    {
                        "_id": "test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "stub": "pizza"
    }
]
```